Induced transformation of functions
Consider a function $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ that is an element of the function space $S$. We're considering two kinds of vector spaces, one is the vector space $V$ of the variables $\mathbf{r}$ and the vector space $S$ of functions. We can construct the transformations $T$ in function space through the transformations of the functions induced by a group of transformations $G$ of the variables $\mathbf{r}$.
The induced transformation $T(G)$ is defined as,
\begin{equation}\tag{1} \label{1}
T(G) \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \psi(G^{-1} \mathbf{r})
\end{equation}
where it is convenient to define the transformed function as $\psi'(\mathbf{r}) = \psi(G^{-1} \mathbf{r})$. Suppose $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ represents the temperature of a body at the point $\mathbf{r}$ in three dimensions and $G$ denotes a rotation of the body about the origin. Then eq.(\ref{1}) ensures that the new function $\psi'(\mathbf{r})$ represents the temperature at $\mathbf{r}$ after the rotation. This is illustrated in the figure below, where $Q$ denotes the point $G^{-1} \mathbf{r}$. Thus, after rotation $G$ the point $Q$ is carried to $P$, since $G(G^{-1} \mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{r}$. Thus, after the rotation the temperature at $P$ denoted by $\psi'(\mathbf{r})$ is what it was at $Q$ before the rotation, namely $\psi(G^{-1} \mathbf{r})$. We then have $\psi'(\mathbf{r}) = \psi(G^{-1} \mathbf{r})$. This is a discussion from the book [1]


I'm not sure I completely understand the discussion. My confusion arises due to the notation used. If $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector describing a point in the body (and not of a point in space) such that when rotating the body $\mathbf{r}$ rotates with the body, then the rotated vector should be labeled as $\mathbf{r}'$. Following the book's argument then in the end we should have,
\begin{equation}\tag{2} \label{2}
T(G) \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \psi(G^{-1} \mathbf{r}')
\end{equation}
such that $G^{-1} \mathbf{r}' = \mathbf{r}$ just describes the old point.
I'll write an explanation and draw my own diagram such that in the end it will match the notation, but the argument will be a bit different (I guess).
Suppose $\psi$ represents the temperature of a body that is depicted by the blue shape in fig.(a), and $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ is the temperature of the body at point $P$ described by the vector $\mathbf{r}$. Rotate the body counterclockwise by applying the transformation $G$, I believe the vector $\mathbf{r}$ is fixed while the body rotates since the vectors $\mathbf{r}$ describe points in space, not of the body (I guess). This can be seen in fig.(b), where the rotated body can be described by a new temperature function $\psi'$. From fig.(a)&(b), it's obvious that $\psi(\mathbf{r}) \neq \psi'(\mathbf{r})$. On the other hand, consider again the old temperature $\psi$ depicted in fig.(c). If we apply the same amount of rotation to $\mathbf{r}$ but in the opposite direction (clockwise), we get a new vector $G^{-1} \mathbf{r}$ describing the point $Q$. From fig.(b)&(c), it is obvious that $\psi'(\mathbf{r}) = \psi(G^{-1} \mathbf{r})$.
So, what eq.(\ref{1}) means is that, we have a function $\psi$ which describes the temperature $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ of the body at point $P$. Applying $T(G)$ on $\psi$ we get the new temperature function $\psi'$ of the rotated body. Evidently, evaluating $\psi'$ at $P$ in space is not the same as evaluating $\psi$ at $P$. In order to get the matching we need to transform $\mathbf{r}$ by $G^{-1}$ and evaluate $\psi$ there which will equal $\psi'(\mathbf{r})$.
I would like to ask if there are any mistakes in my understanding of the situation which is depicted in my figure. Specifically, that the vector $\mathbf{r}$ is fixed while the body rotates which led to the conclusion.

References:
[1] Symmetry in Physics by Elliott, Section 3.7
[2] Symmetry, Broken Symmetry, and Topology in Modern Physics by Guidry & Sun, Example 2.8
[3] Group Theory in Physics by Tung, Section 3.1 Example 7
